# The minimum number of points with normals to fit Ellipsoid.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, mathematical-modeling

Typically 9 points are the minimum number of points required to fit an ellipsoid. In my research I have begun working with methods of fitting models to points while using the surface normal.  This offers more information and can dramatically reduce the needed number of points to fit the model.  I have not found and am struggling to do something similar for ellipsoids. I am not an expert but I am wondering if there is a way to leverage the fact that the normal is proportional to the gradient at a given point on the ellipsoid.

The ellipsoid to be fit should not be limited to the origin on the center or being axis aligned.

Comment: Imposing that the ellipsoid be tangent at a given point to a given tangent plane is "equivalent" to impose to pass through $3$ points. To comment more you should specify better the details of your fitting method.

Comment: I'm not sure what is missing. I'm using large Kinect point cloud data and am trying to fit various shapes. I'm using RANSAC since most shapes make up less than 2% of the data. I have normals and 3D locations of each of the points. RANSAC tends to require less iterations if the required number of sampled points is less. For each shape I have been using the data differently to define a model. For example a sphere. I find where the line defined by the point and normals intersex and that becomes the center. Then I take the average distance from the center to the points and define the radius.

Comment: sorry, I do not have experience with the SW you cite, and cannot help in that.